# MS Outlook Rules - X email in CC or TO but Y Email is neither in CC or TO

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a requirement to setup rules:

1. X Email is in TO or CC
2. Y Email is neither in TO or CC

I couldn't find any option to setup this rule in MS Outlook. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you can try creating followng rules:(Add an action as you want)

[image]

This should works if you all don't use Bcc. Please check whether this works on your side.